# Swagger Parameters and Complex Types

Tags: swagger

In the following Swagger definition, I need the parameter `labelValue` to be of type `LabelValueObject`, so that it will be validated and correctly deserialized. However, I can't figure out the syntax! How can that be done?

```
swagger: "2.0"

paths:
  /competition:
    post:
      parameters:
        - name: labelValue
          in: formData
          type: array
          items:
            type: string       ### this has to be a LabelValueObject ###
      responses:
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/AnyResponse"

definitions:
  AnyResponse:
    properties:
      any:
        type: string
  LabelValueObject:
    properties:
      label:
        type: string
      value:
        type: string
    required:
      - label
      - value
```

Comment: Does this parameter needs to be located in a formData?

Comment: You're right. I could set it to body and use a schema $ref I guess... I'm new to Swagger, so I missed that. If that's where you were going with your question, please post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to pass an object as a parameter is to put it in the body (`in: body`) and then define this object in `schema` (inline definition or reference to an predefined object with `$ref`). Here's a full example:

```
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  title: A dummy title
  version: 1.0.0

paths:
  /competition:
    post:
      parameters:
        - name: labelValue
          in: body
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/LabelValueObject'
      responses:
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/AnyResponse"

definitions:
  AnyResponse:
    properties:
      any:
        type: string
  LabelValueObject:
    properties:
      label:
        type: string
      value:
        type: string
    required:
      - label
      - value
```